# Group pandas DataFrame on column and sum it while retaining the number of sumed observations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 2, 2], 'comp': [-0.10,0.20,-0.10, 0.4], 'word': ['boy','girl','man', 'woman']})
```

I would like to group the dataframe on `id`, and calculate the sum of corresponding `comp` as well as get a new column called `n_obs` that tracks how many rows(ids) were summed up.

I tried using `df.groupby('id').sum()` but this is not quite producing the results that I want.

I'd like an output on the below form:

```
id   comp   n_obs
1    0.1    2
2    0.3    2
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` with `.agg()`:

```py
df.groupby("id").agg(comp=("comp", "sum"), n_obs=("id", "count"))
```

This outputs:

```py
    comp  n_obs
id
1    0.1      2
2    0.3      2
```